# Disable some option from search in chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have select box with `chosen` Jquery

```
<select class="chosenvic">
    <option value="vikas">Vikas</option>
    <option value="jai">Jai</option>
    <option value="raj">Raj</option>
    <option value="1" >**Add New Option**</option>
</select>
```

Whenever we search content with chosen search feature, if the record does not exist in select box like Jitendra, then its showing no result Found.

And **Add new option** also removed from select box. I don't want to remove **Add new option** because I have added feature for add new entries with Add new option.

Comment: can you show us your js code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `no_results_text` and add an element to it for egs, button like,

```
$('.chosenvic').chosen({no_results_text: "<button>Add New Option</button>"});
$('.chosen-container').on('click','button',function(){
    // do your stuff
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/ham4m7c2/)**

Comment: Thanks Rohan, its really helpful for me. :)

Comment: If you think that this is correct answer then mark it as correct answer.